# Select from two slightly similar tables with complex conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 4 tables in an oracle database with a complex relationship and they do not have useful primary keys.

**TableA**

```
+------+------+------+------+------+-----------------+
| ColA | ColX | ColY | ColZ | ColZa|      A          |
+------+------+------+------+------+-----------------+
| k9   | a1   | c1   | g1   | z1   | 2018-02-19      |
| k9   | a1   | c1   | g3   | z2   | 2018-02-02      |
| k10  | a2   | f3   | g1   | z3   | 2018-02-09      |
| k10  | a    | b    | c    | d    | 2018-02-03      |
| k    | a    | b    | c1   | z2   | 2018-02-01      |
| k9   | a1   | c1   | c9   | z5   | 2018-02-04      |
| k9   | a1   | c1   | c2   | z5   | 2018-02-03      |
| k9   | a1   | c1   | g2   | z5   | 2018-02-03      |
+------+------+------+------+------+-----------------+
```

**TableB**

```
+------+------+------+------+------+----------------+
| ColA | ColX | ColY | ColZ | ColZa|      B         |
+------+------+------+------+------+----------------+
| e    | a3   | f    | g1   | i    | 2018-02-03     |
| e3   | a1   | f1   | g3   | d2   | 2018-02-04     |
| k9   | a1   | c1   | g2   | z5   | 2018-02-08     |
| e4   | a4   | f2   | g2   | i2   | 2018-02-07     |
| e5   | a1   | f1   | g1   | d2   | 2018-02-06     |
| k9   | a1   | c1   | g1   | d2   | 2018-02-22     |
+------+------+------+------+------+----------------+
```

**TableC**

```
+------+------+------+----------------+
| ColA | ColX | ColY |      C         |
+------+------+------+----------------+
| ab   | c2   | c2   | cx             |
| k9   | a1   | c1   | cy             |
| cd   | a2   | c3   | cy             |
| ef   | c2   | c4   | cz             |
| ef   | c2   | c2   | cz             |
+------+------+------+----------------+
```

**TableD**

```
+------+------+------+----------------+
| ColA | ColX | ColY |       D        |
+------+------+------+----------------+
| e    | a    | f    | dx             |
| e1   | a    | a    | dy             |
| e2   | a1   | a1   | dz             |
+------+------+------+----------------+
```

Some business logic requires me to select and combine data from `TableA` and `TableB`
**The Problem:** 
Fetch records `ColA, ColX, ColY, ColZ, ColZa, A, B` in TableA AND/OR TableB for cases where pseudo key ColA_ColX_ColY have value ColZ = 'g1', with merge on `ColA | ColX | ColY | ColZ | ColZa`.
I used the word 'pseudo' here because it is not really a key but it's just a means to identify the records of interest in TablesA and TablesB.

To construct a valid key, count(colY) must be 1 for value in colX in TableC and TableD (this is actually the case in all four tables but if you only consider distinct values but I am suppose to use only TableC and TableD since it is more explicit)

**The process:** 
In the result table below, I should get row1 in table TableA because 'a1' has only one count(ColY)=1 in TableC but I ignored row1 in TableB and row3 in TableA because count(ColY) is not equal to 1 in either TableC or TableD
Now that I have a value 'a1' from TableC.ColX which matches my criteria, I select all records in TableA and TableB where ColX = 'a1' and ColY = 'c1' and ColA = 'k9'

**My desired result**

```
+------+------+------+------+------+-----------------+----------------+
| ColA | ColX | ColY | ColZ | ColZa|      A          |        B       |
+------+------+------+------+------+-----------------+----------------|
| k9   | a1   | c1   | g1   | z1   | 2018-02-19      |    [null]      |
| k9   | a1   | c1   | g3   | z2   | 2018-02-02      |    [null]      |
| k9   | a1   | c1   | c9   | z5   | 2018-02-04      |    [null]      |
| k9   | a1   | c1   | c2   | z5   | 2018-02-03      |    [null]      |
| k9   | a1   | c1   | g2   | z5   | 2018-02-03      | 2018-02-08     |
| k9   | a1   | c1   | g4   | d2   |     [null]      | 2018-02-22     |
+------+------+------+------+------+-----------------+----------------+
```

So, I wrote a query similar to

```
select a.ColX, a.ColY, a.ColZ, a.ColZa, a.A, b.B from TableA a FULL OUTER JOIN TableB b ON a.ColX=b.ColX AND a.ColY=b.ColY AND a.ColZ=b.ColZ 
 where (
   a.ColX IN 
   (select ColX from TableA where 
     ColX IN 
        (select ColX from TableC group by ColX HAVING count(ColY)=1) and 
     ColX in 
        (select distinct ColX from TableB where ColZ = 'g1'and B > trunc(sysdate) - 365) 
    group by ColX having count(distinct ColY)=1) 


 OR 
   b.ColX IN
   (select ColX from TableA where 
     ColX IN
        (select ColX from TableC group by ColX HAVING count(ColY)=1) and
     ColX in
        (select distinct ColX from TableB where ColZ = 'g1' and B > trunc(sysdate) - 365)
    group by ColX having count(distinct ColY)=1));
```

I have no control over the data model here. How do I make my query work? 
The data in TableA and TableB are in 100,000 records and data in TableC and TableD are up to a million.

SQL is not my area of expertise and I really hope I am not going too off the mark here.

Comment: I don't see clear logic for how the joins are taking place.  That aside, these tables all look very similar which has a bit of a design smell.  Even if you can't change things, you can still hopefully voice your opinion.

Comment: Why is the purpose of that `ColZ = 'g1'` in your query attempt? I think you need to elaborate a little bit more the explanation of the query you are trying to build

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have edited the comments to give better clarity.

Comment: @JorgeY. 'g1' is a value I need to be in the search query, but not just any 'g1', It must match the business requirement

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what your query is supposed to do, but as a pure refactoring exercise I get this:

```
with whatever as
       ( select colx
         from   tablea
         where  colx in
                ( select colx
                  from   tablec
                  group by colx having count(colb) = 1
                  union all
                  select colx
                  from   tableb
                  where  colz = 'g1'
                  and    b > trunc(sysdate) - 365 )
         group  by colx
         having count(distinct colza) = 1 )
select a.colx, a.coly, a.colz, a.colza, a.a, b.b
from   tablea a
       full outer join tableb b
            on  a.colx = b.colx
            and a.coly = b.coly
            and a.colz = b.colz
       join whatever w
            on w.colx in (a.colx, b.colx);
```